# Is there any meaning to this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any meaning to this problem? I added it to my solution.

---

Let $\mathbb P_n$ be a linear space consisting of polynomials of degree n with
real coefficients. Consider linear transformations $\phi$ and $\psi$ from
$\mathbb P_n \to \mathbb P_n$, defined by, $\phi(f(x))=f(x+1)$ and
$\psi(f)(x)=f'(x)$. Suppose $A$ and $D$ be the matrix relative to the basis $1,
x, \ldots, x^n$ for $\phi,\:\psi$. Show that

$$ A = E +\frac 1 {1!} D + \frac 1 {2!} D^2 + \cdots + \frac 1 {n!} D^n $$

Let $\beta = (1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n)^T$. Then
\begin{align*}A &= [\phi]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} [\phi(1)]_\beta &
[\phi(x)]_\beta & [\phi(x^2)]_\beta & \ldots & [\phi(x^n)]_\beta \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & \ldots & n \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & _nC_2 \\
&&&\cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}D &= [\psi]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} [\psi(1)]_\beta &
[\psi(x)]_\beta & [\psi(x^2)]_\beta & \ldots & [\psi(x^n)]_\beta \end{bmatrix}
\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
&&&\cdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: I find it's an interesting way to prove the matrix identity

Comment: What's the way?